# Can anyone explain me about real and complex euclidean space?

Tags: inner-products

Is euclidean space a linear space where inner product exists?

If $V$ is a complex linear space, then do there complex numbers $x,y$ in $V$ such that $\langle x,y \rangle$ is complex?

And

I don't understand this transformation.

$T: V\to E$, where $V$ is a subspace of Euclidean space.

Is $V$ a linear space? and why is it a subspace of Euclidean space?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest,I don't completely understand your question. V is a subset of E where it's closed under addition and 0 is in V. A subspace by definition is also a linear or vector space. So T is a local isomorphism(linear transformation) of E from the subspace to the larger space.

On a complex vector space, we can certainly define a complex inner product **in addition** to the usual Euclidean inner product. The inner product can be defined completely abstractly via axioms so it's irrelevant whether the spaces are over real or complex fields.

For more details,[take a look at this:](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnlafolder/la12.pdf)